# Mobile Webkit: reliably detect viewable area in all situations?

Tags: javascript, dom, mobile-webkit

Short version:
In my mobile web app I want to always detect the *viewable area* of the screen (e.g., the space between the top of the soft keyboard (if present) and the bottom of the titlebar), so I can adjust my layout, without zooming, and keep the page completely visible on-screen at all times.  Is there any reliable way to do this?

---

Longer version:
In the app I'm grabbing all touch events and controlling panning and zooming myself.  Control bars are fixed at top and bottom of the screen, always visible. My veiwport settings are:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;
maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no">
```

My wish is to always adapt my page layout to the viewable area of the browser window, so nothing is ever off-screen.  So, when the keyboard appears or disappears, or when orientation changes, I need to detect the width and height and re-layout accordingly.

If not for the on-screen keyboard, **window.innerWidth** and **window.innerHeight** would suffice. When the keyboard appears, though, things get wacky (works only under certain tightly controlled conditions).  And heaven forbid there's an orientation change while the keyboard is up.

Is there anything in the DOM that can tell me what I want?  I really would prefer to figure this out dynamically rather than hardwire the size of the interface elements into my code, but I'll resort to that if there's no other way.

Sorry for the verbosity, it's hard to capture all the weirdness I've been experiencing.  My testing has been predominantly on an iPad running 3.2 and an iPhone running 4.1; behavior has been consistently inconsistent across both.

Comment: I guess if one knew this, he could create a pretty neat KVM viewer application, true?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you're after is probably `screen.availHeight` which shows the height of the screen minus the title bar. This doesn't change when you bring up the on-screen keyboard or rotate the screen, however, even using the `window.onresize` event. I can't think of a way to take account of that I'm afraid.

Comment: Yup, that's what I've found.  Ultimate solution requires keeping track of when the keyboard is up, and knowing the exact size of it and subtracting it out. Too bad, seems like an oversight in the implementation.